# Converting images to one-hot array and back returns black images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I have a numpy array of numpy array of 3 grayscale images with just 0 and 255 values (`shape: (3, 512, 512)`). I turned them to one-hot encodings into 2 classes using `tf.one_hot` (`shape: (3, 512, 512, 2)`). Now, I am trying to get them back to original form through `np.argmax`. But when I read the images, they are all black.

```
    labels = []
    labels.append(label_1)
    labels.append(label_2)
    labels.append(label_3)
    labels = np.asarray(labels)

    print(labels.shape)                # (3, 512, 512)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 2)     # (3, 512, 52, 2)
    print(labels.shape)
    #print(labels)

    labels = labels.eval()             # to convert to numpy array from tensor

    imgs = np.argmax(labels, axis=3)   # also tried tf.argmax
    print(imgs.shape)                  # (3, 512, 512)

    for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
        image = imgs[i]
        print(img.shape)               # (512, 512)
        indices = np.where(image > 0) 
        print(indices)                 # array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64)
        print(indices)
        image = Image.fromarray(image, 'L')
        image.show()                   # black images, values all zero
```

I am sure I am missing something pretty simple but can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I checked for indices where the array has non-zero values. But all values seem to be zeros. So, not an issue of displaying the image. I think the problem is with `argmax` but I do not know what.

Answer (score 1):

Argmax returns the index where the maximum occurs over some dimension. In your case you are taking the argmax over a dimension of length 2, so it returns either a 0 or a 1 for every location in your (3, 512, 512) array. Both options are very dark on the 8-bit scale and will appear black! You have to make sure you display the binary images as binary.

I haven't used this library before, but maybe try `mode='I'`? or some of the other modes here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes. The return type of that argmax is important.

Comment: Oh yes! How did I not see this?!! Thanks

Comment: I checked with np.where() Everything seems to be 0

Comment: What is in `labels` and `imgs`? Where does it start being all zeros? Is `labels` filled with greater values in the first of that 4th dimension always?

Comment: Its becoming zero after the one_hot. Maybe I am doing the one_hot wrong. Btw it is a grayscale image with just 0 and 255 values; not binary.

Comment: @Anakin How to do one_hot encoding for grayscale images . I'm facing the same issue now